# Linux way to increase more column in the text format

Tags: python, linux, perl, awk, sed

I would like to add one column

I generated below table format (.txt file and tab delimited)

```
    ID      ALPA
    1        A
    1        A
    1        B
    1        B
    1        C
    2        A
    2        A
    2        B
    2        B
    2        C
    2        C
```

There are two same ALPA in one ID 
like two A in ID 1
but in case of C of ID 1 contain only one 
then I would like to comment same row like below

```
    ID      ALPA     Remark
    1        A
    1        A
    1        B
    1        B
    1        C       Error : There is only one ALPA exist
    2        A
    2        A
    2        B
    2        B
    2        C
    2        C
```

Anyone know which one is better way to do it?

Thank you all!

Comment: are there always two As and two Bs for same ID? what if an ID has single A B and C?

Comment: Then that is error I have to show error message same as C !

Comment: Is it an error if there are more than two?

Comment: Yes then it should show message too !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is awk line, it doesn't require your input file to be sorted:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{print $0,"Remark"}
{k=$1FS$2;x[NR]=k;c[k]++}
END{for(i=2;i<=NR;i++)printf "%s%s\n", x[i],(c[x[i]]!=2? FS "ERROR":"")}' file
```

with your data, output:

```
ID      ALPA    Remark
1       A
1       A
1       B
1       B
1       C       ERROR
2       A
2       A
2       B
2       B
2       C
2       C
```

You can write meaningful error msg, I just made it "ERROR"

### Update

add a relative readable version:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" 'NR==1{print $0,"Remark"}
        {key=$1FS$2; lines[NR]=key; count[key]++}
        END{for(i=2;i<=NR;i++)
                        if(count[lines[i]]!=2)
                                print lines[i], "ERROR"
                        else
                                print lines[i]}' file
```

Comment: Oh I wonder if ID is ABC01_DEF , ABC02_DEF then how can I cut off before _

Comment: @clear.choi that would be another question. you can first test my awk line with `FOO0x_BAR` it should work too.

Comment: Oh I am sorry actual file ID contain like that so I cannot test directly actual file ABC01_DEF , ABC01_GHI, this is same ID because of ABC01 is same

Comment: @clear.choi I cannot agree with Ed more..  but here is the way to cook egg, hope you next time think twice before posting question. `awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{sub(/_.*$/, "",$1)}7' file` this will cut the `_BAR` from `$1`.  You can actually merge it into the awk line in answer. well, good luck. the line in this comment I didn't test. if it didn't go with your real data, find out why and try to fix by yourself.

Comment: @jaypal here is an awk oneliner for you, to know the way of boil your egg :-)  `awk 'BEGIN{print "\x52-\x54-\x46-\x4d" }' <<<"How To boil an egg"`

Comment: I just realized what was bothering me about this solution - it's the negative test. While it will work just fine, I find that testing negatives as in `if (x!=2) do_A; else do_B` is less clear and more error prone than testing positives as in `if (x==2) do_B; else do_A`. In particular if you never use a negative in a condition then you avoid the risk of someone coming along later with an enhancement and negating that condition and making it the dreaded double negative.

Comment: @EdMorton true! I remembered sometime long ago I have read about the coding style. one item is "using positive conditions". Negative may let a brain twist `if(!somethingNotValid())` :-D

Comment: @Kent - exactly. I see that all the time in other peoples code that I need to modify - they've used "Not" in variable names, function names, enum names, etc, often because they dont know English well enough to know what the positive word is for the opposite condition and didn't think to look it up in a thesaurus, but also often because they just dont understand that using negative terminology is a problem. Immensely frustrating and often wrong, e.g. "How to cook not a chicken" != "How to cook an egg" :-).

Comment: @EdMorton i see, I should do `if(!sthInvalid())` without "not"

Comment: ITYM `if(sthValid())` with neither the `not` nor the `!`.

Comment: Thank you so much Kent I will test as soon as possible :)

Comment: @Kent I am sorry for making a confused

Comment: @Kent Finally I successfully did it based on you guided me Thank you so much!!